# use componentWillMount without a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

with react-native, I want to use componentWillMount without using a class

```
  await Font.loadAsync({
    gotham_medium: require("../../assets/GothamMedium_1.ttf")
  });
}

const Button = (props: TouchableOpacityProps & ButtonProps) => (
  <TouchableOpacity {...props} style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

export default Button;
```

But I have a problem on the device :
[error on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEASB.png)

Comment: Take a look at useEffect

Answer (score 4):

It says the problem is on this line (and it is):

```js
async componentWillMount = () => {
```

When you use an async function, the `async` keyword goes right before `() =>` (a vanilla js syntax error). Like this:

```js
componentWillMount = async () => {
```

But, that's not the main problem. When not using a class, you need the `useEffect` hook. 
So, try something like this (the whole component, and deleting componentWillMount):

```js
const Button = (props: TouchableOpacityProps & ButtonProps) => {
  useEffect(async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      gotham_medium: require("../../assets/GothamMedium_1.ttf")
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity {...props} style={styles.button}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

And at the top of the file:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: I tried your code and It always return me an error : TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _react.useEffect)...')

This error is located at:
    in Button (at App.tsx:11)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hooks for this,

from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html),

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of `useEffect` Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

And

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

```
useEffect(async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
     gotham_medium: require("../../assets/GothamMedium_1.ttf")
  });
},[]);
```

Comment: I tried your code and It always return me an error : TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _react.useEffect)...')

This error is located at:
    in Button (at App.tsx:11)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)

Comment: You need to import `useEffect` like - `import React, {useEffect} from 'react'`

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: my code https://playcode.io/365495?tabs=script.js,preview,console and the error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _react.useEffect)...') This error is located at: in Button (at App.tsx:11) in RCTView (at View.js:44)

Comment: I can't see any error here, It is working fine and printing `Hello World` in `console` as well as in `preview`. What is the issue?

Comment: Can you also add your `View.js` file where you are using Button.

Comment: it is my app show hello world, you can take a look where I call the component Button https://playcode.io/365495?tabs=script.js,preview,console

Comment: This code is not runnable. I cannot see the error you are facing.

Comment: you can download the project from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/napg7371kme5wsj/expo_app.zip?dl=0 it is with react-native expo

Comment: I got the error. You are using `"react": "16.5.0",` and Hooks are added in React 16.8. Just upgrade your react version to 16.8 and your code will work. To do so change `"react": "16.5.0",` to `"react": "^16.8.2",` in your `package.json` file and then use command to install latest version of react like, `npm install` / `yarn install`.

Comment: Also destroy your `dropbox` link.

Comment: now, I have a different error:  Unable to resolve "schedule/tracking" from "node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js": Module 'schedule/tracking' does not exist in the Haste module map

Comment: This is because your node module package is broken. Delete node_modules folder and try to install again.

Comment: I did and I changed my schedule version, it works now npm i schedule@0.4.0 --save-dev , but I have an issue with hooks . Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: `function Button(props: TouchableOpacityProps & ButtonProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadFont() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        gotham_medium: require("../../assets/GothamMedium_1.ttf")
      });
    }
    loadFont()
  }, []);
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity {...props} style={styles.button}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};`

Comment: Have to checked these - 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. Your `react` and `react-dom` packages should be latest version that is possibly 16.8. Also make sure you have only 1 import for `react`